# Wait for an own function (which returns a promise) before tests are executed

Tags: javascript, cypress

I have my own function (which calls a test controller server to reset the database). It returns a promise which completes when the DB have been successfully resetted.

```
function resetDatabase(){
  // returns a promise for my REST api call.
}
```

My goal is to be able to execute it before all tests.

```
describe('Account test suite', function () {

  // how can I call resetDb here and wait for the result
  // before the tests below are invoked?

  it('can log in', function () {
        cy.visit(Cypress.config().testServerUrl + '/Account/Login/')

        cy.get('[name="UserName"]').type("admin");
        cy.get('[name="Password"]').type("123456");
        cy.get('#login-button').click();
  });

  // .. and more test

})
```

How can I do that in cypress?

**Update**

I've tried

```
  before(() => {
    return resetDb(Cypress.config().apiServerUrl);
  });
```

But then I get an warning saying:

> Cypress detected that you returned a promise in a test, but also invoked one or more cy commands inside of that promise

I'm not invoking `cy` in `resetDb()`.

Comment: from what I know, there should be a `wait` method where you can directly wait for your api, but I may be wrong
p.s. with the `wrap` method instead you should be able to wrap an ES6 promise and trasform it to a Cypress promise

Comment: @quirimmo Wait takes either a timeout or an `alias` from a previous command: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/wait.html#Syntax

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Cypress have promises ([Cypress.Promise](https://docs.cypress.io/api/utilities/promise.html#Syntax)), but they are not real promises, more like [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). In fact, Cypress isn't 100% compatible with real promises, they might, or might not, work.

Think of `Cypress.Promise` as a Task or an Action. They are executed sequentially with all other cypress commands.

To get your function into the Cypress pipeline you can use [custom commands](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html#Syntax). The documentation doesn't state it, but you can return a `Cypress.Promise` from them.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('resetDb', function () {
  var apiServerUrl = Cypress.config().apiServerUrl;
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    httpRequest('PUT', apiServerUrl + "/api/test/reset/")
      .then(function (data) {
        resolve();
      })
      .catch(function (err) {
        reject(err);
      });
  });
});
```

That command can then be executed from the test itself, or as in my case from `before()`.

```
describe('Account', function () {
  before(() => {
    cy.resetDb();
  });

  it('can login', function () {
    // test code
  });

})
```

Comment: What is the method `httpRequest` , do you remember if it come from cypress, or a separate library -- maybe you defined it? Cypress has `cy.request(...)`. 

Also I wonder how your original `resetDb` function was different; (compare your original function that caused the error ("...but also invoked one or more cy commands inside of that promise"); vs the custom command you have here which does not have the error), is the only difference that it became a custom command, vs being a standalone function?

Comment: httpRequest: it was a function that I coded myself. I changed the resetDb to be able to specify the HTTP server address in cypress configuration file, instead of hardcoding it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `cy.wrap( promise )`, although there might still be a bug where it [never times out](https://gitter.im/cypress-io/cypress?at=59f8a1ee614889d47522dda1) (haven't tested).

Otherwise, you can use `cy.then()` (which is undocumented, can break in the future, and I'm def not doing any favors by promoting internal APIs):

```
cy.then(() => {
    return myAsyncFunction();
});
```

You can use both of these commands at the top-level of spec like you'd use any command and it'll be enqueued into cypress command queue and executed in order.

But unlike `cy.wrap` (IIRC), `cy.then()` supports passing a callback, which means you can execute your async function *at the time* of the cy command being executed, not at the start of the spec (because expressions passed to cy commands evaluate immediately) --- that's what I'm doing in the example above.